# Trying to Understand Memory Leak in my Linked List Program

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, linked-list

I turned in an application dealing with dynamic memory allocation with a memory leak.  This is my first assignment in this category, so its fairly new to me.  My professor graded the assignment already and told me I had a memory leak.  The memory leak is in the `DeleteNode()`function, where I'm deleting the node.  Can someone explain to me why its a memory leak?  I'm extremely new with this subject and I know I'm missing it, I just need it pointed out I think.  There may be other issues outside of my memory leak (a few places I forgot to check to see if memory was successfully allocated), but those I understand, its just the memory leak I need help with.  Also, I only wrote the `AddNode()`, `DeleteNode()`, `BuildList()`, and `ZapList()` functions, I didn't code the rest, it was a shell that was already written for us.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <new>
//#include <process.h>        //  Needed for call to exit
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    enum  { DUMMY_VALUE = 1 };  //  Value () stored in dummy head node.
    char  Ch;                   //  Holds the char data.
    Node *Link;                 //  Points to another struct of type Node.
};

typedef Node* NodePtr;

void AbortProgram (void);

void AddNode (char NewChar,  NodePtr List);

void BuildList (NodePtr List);

void ZapList (NodePtr P);

void DeleteNode (char CharToDelete, NodePtr List, int &CharFound);

void StartList (NodePtr &List);

void ShowList (NodePtr List);

void DisplayMenuAndGetMenuChoice (char &MenuChoice);

void TestAddNode (NodePtr List);

void TestBuildList (NodePtr List);

void TestDeleteNode (NodePtr List);

void TestZapList (NodePtr List);
/*****************************  main   ********************************/

int main(void)
{
    NodePtr List = NULL;

    char MenuChoice;

    system("cls");
    cout << "This program allows you to test the routines needed \n"
    "for homework 8. \n\n";

    StartList(List);
    if (List == NULL)                        //  Unexpected error.
        AbortProgram ();

    do
    {
        DisplayMenuAndGetMenuChoice(MenuChoice);

        switch( MenuChoice )
        {
            case 'Q':  break;                // Exit program

            case 'B':  TestBuildList(List);
                break;

            case 'A':  TestAddNode(List);
                break;

            case 'D':  TestDeleteNode(List);
                break;

            case 'Z':  TestZapList(List);
                break;

            default :  cout << "\nError: '" << MenuChoice
                << "' is not an option \n\n";
        }
    }
    while ( MenuChoice != 'Q' );

    return 0;
}

/*********************   DisplayMenuAndGetMenuChoice *********************
 Displays a menu of options and reads the user's choice into the
 parameter MenuChoice. Unbuffered input is used, so the user does
 not have to enter a newline character after typing a menu choice.
 The MenuChoice is upcased.
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void DisplayMenuAndGetMenuChoice (char &MenuChoice)
{
    const char* Option[] = {"B(uildList", "A(ddNode", "D(eleteNode",
        " Z(apList", "Q(uit", "" };

    char DottedLine[] ="\n- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - "
    "- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n ";
    int K = 0;

    cout << DottedLine;

    while ( Option[K][0] != 0 )  // while we haven't gotten to ""
    {
        cout << Option[K];         // Display menu option
        cout << "  ";              // Add some white space.
        ++K;
    }

    cout << "=> ";
    MenuChoice = toupper(cin.get());
    cin.ignore(10,'\n');

    cout <<  DottedLine;
}

/************************    TestAddNode  ********************************
 Facilitates the testing of the function AddNode, a function which
 adds a node to the tail end of a linked list. If the enter key is
 pressed in response to the prompt, it is assumed that the user
 wants to exit and this function is aborted.
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void TestAddNode (NodePtr List)
{
    char NewChar;

    cout << "\n\n----------------   Testing AddNode   -------------------\n\n";

    cout << "Character to be added? ";
    NewChar = cin.get();
    cin.ignore();

    if (NewChar == '\n')  // User pressed just enter key.
    {
        cout << "Aborting AddNode...";
        return;
    }

    cout << NewChar;
    cout << " --  Adding \'" << NewChar  << "\'";

    AddNode (NewChar, List);

    cout << "\n\nThe new list: ";
    ShowList(List);
}

/*************************    TestBuildList     **************************
 Facilitates the testing of the function BuildList, which is supposed
 to build an ordered linked list of characters.
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void TestBuildList (NodePtr List)
{
    cout << "\n\n=================  Testing BuildList  ===================";
    cout << "\n\nType the characters for the list -  "
    "when finished, press enter key\n\n ->";

    BuildList(List);

    cout << "\n\nAfter BuildList, List = ";
    ShowList(List);
}

/***********************    TestDeleteNode   *****************************
 Facilitates the testing of DeleteNode, a function which is supposed
 to delete characters from a linked list.
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void TestDeleteNode (NodePtr List)
{
    int  CharFound;
    char CharToBeDeleted;

    cout << "\n\n*****************   Testing DeleteNode   *******************";

    cout << "\n\nCharacter to be deleted? ";
    CharToBeDeleted = cin.get();
    cin.ignore();

    DeleteNode (CharToBeDeleted, List, CharFound);

    if ( CharFound )
        cout << "\n\n'" << CharToBeDeleted << "' has been deleted,";
    else
        cout << "\n\n'" << CharToBeDeleted << "' was not in the list,";

    cout << "\n\nList = ";
    ShowList(List);
}

/***********************    TestZapList  *********************************
 Facilitates the testing of ZapList, a function that is supposed to
 return all storage allocated for a linked list to the heap (except the
 storage occupied by the dummy head node.
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void TestZapList (NodePtr List)
{
    cout << "\n\n^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   Calling ZapList  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^";

    ZapList(List);

    cout << "\n\nList = ";
    ShowList(List);
}

/****************************  AbortProgram   ****************************
 Displays an error message and returns a non-zero error code to
 the operating system.

 Requires exit function prototyped in process.h.
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void AbortProgram (void)
{
    cout << "\n\n\a A error has occurred while using the new operator. \n"
    "Returning to the operating system\n";
    cout << "Press ENTER key to continue: ";
    cin.get();
    exit(1);
}

/************************    StartList  *********************************
 DESCRIPTION   Creates an empty list, i.e. a singly linked list that
 contains only a dummy head node.

 PARAMETER

 OUT, List   A pointer to the head node of the list. If the
 dynamic memory allocation is unsuccessful, List will
 hold NULL on exit.

 PRECONDITION  List points to NULL. If List points to an actual node,
 calling this routine will create inaccessable memory.
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void StartList (NodePtr &List)
{
    List = new(nothrow) Node;
    if (List == NULL)
        return;                        // Memory allocation error.

    List->Ch   = List->DUMMY_VALUE;  // Fill in dummy head node fields
    List->Link = NULL;               // Initialize end of list.
}

/*************************   ShowList  ***********************************
 DESCRIPTION  Displays the character field of all of the nodes in List, a
 singly linked list with a dummy head node. The list is
 enclosed in quotes.

 The constant MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE controls the maximum
 number of characters displayed before a newline char
 is displayed.

 PARAMETER

 IN, List   A pointer to a singly linked list with a dummy head node.

 NOTE         To facilitate debugging this routine displays "NULL"
 if called with List == NULL.
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void ShowList (NodePtr List)
{
    const int MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE = 50;

    int CharCount = 0;

    if ( List == NULL )
    {
        cout << " NULL LIST\n\n";
        return;
    }

    cout << "\"";                 //  Display quote for ease of testing.
    while ( List->Link != NULL )
    {
        List = List->Link;
        cout << List->Ch;
        if ( List-> Ch != '\n' )   // Increment CharCount unless newline
            ++CharCount;             //   char is encountered in List
        else
            CharCount = 0;
        if ( CharCount % MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE == 0 )
            cout << "\n     ";
    }

    cout << "\"\n\n";
}

/*****************************   ZapList  ********************************
 DESCRIPTION  Frees all the storage space currently occupied by the
 linked list pointed to by List. Does NOT delete the delete
 the dummy head node.

 PARAMETER

 OUT, List  A pointer to a singly linked list with a dummy head node.
 After this call, List will contain only the dummy head node.

 PRECONDITION List must point to a linked list that has a dummy head node
 and a tail node that points at NULL.
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void ZapList (NodePtr List)
{
    NodePtr Temp;

    Temp=List->Link;//Temp holds position of first Node after dummy node

    while (Temp != NULL)
    {
        List->Link=List->Link->Link;//rerouting dummy node pointer to skip next node and point to one after

        delete Temp;

        Temp=List->Link;
    }
}

/****************************   AddNode  *********************************
 DESCRIPTION  Adds a node containing NewChar to the end of List.

 PARAMETERS

 IN, NewChar The character to be added to the end of the list.

 IN, List    A pointer to a singly linked list with a dummy head node.
 The value of List (address of dummy head node) is not
 changed by this routine, so List is passed by value.
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void AddNode (char NewChar, NodePtr List)
{
    NodePtr NewNode;
    NodePtr PlaceHolder;

    if (List->Link == NULL) // this if statement is used when the list coming in is empty (containing just the dummy)
    {
        List->Link = new Node;

        List->Link->Ch = NewChar;

        return;
    }

    PlaceHolder=List->Link; //placeholder and NewNode both point to first node after dummy node
    NewNode=List->Link;

    while (NewNode != NULL)
    {
        NewNode=PlaceHolder->Link; //Advance NewNode one node down the line

        if (NewNode != NULL) // if NewNode is not poing to Null, allow it to point at same value as NewNode
            PlaceHolder=NewNode;
    }                        //After loop, NewNode will be pointing at Null
                             //Placeholder will be one position behind NewNode

    NewNode= new Node;
    NewNode->Link = NULL;
    NewNode->Ch=NewChar;
    PlaceHolder->Link = NewNode;
}

/****************************    DeleteNode   ****************************
 DESCRIPTION  Deletes the first node of List that contains the char
 CharToDelete. The storage occupied by the deleted
 node is returned to the heap.

 PARAMETERS

 IN, CharToDelete  The character to be deleted.

 IN, List    A pointer to a singly linked list with a dummy head node.
 The value of List is not changed by this routine but the
 linked list itself is changed.

 OUT, CharFound Set to 1 if the CharToDelete is found and deleted and
 0 otherwise.
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void DeleteNode (char CharToDelete, NodePtr List, int &CharFound)
{
    NodePtr NodeToBeDeleted;
    NodePtr PlaceHolder;

    NodeToBeDeleted=List->Link; //Both NodeToBeDeleted and Placeholder point to first node after dummy
    PlaceHolder=List->Link;

    if (List->Link == NULL)// this if-statement is here for empty linked lists coming in
    {                      // immediately set CharFound to 0 and end function
        CharFound=0;
        return;
    }

    while (CharFound != 1) // as soon as character is found, break out
    {
        if (NodeToBeDeleted->Ch == CharToDelete) // check to see if CharToDelete is found
        {
            delete NodeToBeDeleted;
            CharFound = 1;
        }

        if (CharFound == 0) // if not found, advance NodeToBeDeleted to the next postion
            NodeToBeDeleted=PlaceHolder->Link;

        if (NodeToBeDeleted == NULL) // as soon as NodeToBeDeleted points to null, stop testing
            return;

        if (NodeToBeDeleted->Ch != CharToDelete)
            PlaceHolder = NodeToBeDeleted;
        // only advance Placeholder to NodeToBeDeleted if CharToBeDeleted
        // isn't found. Once found, placeHolder remains one position behind
        // to allow linking of the list one node before deleted node
        // to one node after deleted node
    }

    PlaceHolder->Link=PlaceHolder->Link->Link;

    NodeToBeDeleted = NULL;

}

/****************************   BuildList    *****************************
 DESCRIPTION   Builds a singly linked list with a dummy head node. The
 characters in the list are in the same order in which the
 user enters them, i.e. new characters are added to the tail
 end of the list.

 Input terminates when the enter key is pressed.

 PARAMETERS

 IN, List    A pointer to a singly linked list with a dummy head node.
 It is imperative that List be initialized before calling
 this routine.

 NOTE          Before building the new list, ZapList is called. This
 ensures that a memory leak does not develop.
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/
void BuildList (NodePtr List)
{
    char NewChar;
    NodePtr CurrentNode;

    ZapList(List);// ADDED AFTER IT WAS GRADED FOR HW9

    cin.get(NewChar);

    while (NewChar != '\n')
    {
        CurrentNode = new Node;    // attempt to create new node and have CurrentNode point to it

        if (CurrentNode == NULL)
            return;

        CurrentNode->Link = NULL;  //in new node, have node Link pointer point to NULL
        CurrentNode->Ch=NewChar;

        List->Link=CurrentNode;    //connect the newly created and filled node (Current Node) to list
        List=List->Link;           //advance List to next pointer

        cin.get(NewChar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. If you think/told that the problem is in DeleteNode(), then no need to confuse readers with all your code

Comment: There are over 400 lines of code here, which is just too much to go through to find a memory leak. Reduce this to a [mcve] and post that instead, but no doubt in doing so you'll uncover your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dammit, snipered.

The below answer by Ivan is correct. It will generally not segfault because nothing actually hapens to the freed memory until you re-allocate it, it still contains valid data when you are referencing it, so the problem will usually not show up.

The memory leak comes from the fact that you are setting the Link pointer on a variable that is being (or in this case has already been) deleted. You therefore loose the handle to the rest of your list.

Your PlaceHolder pointer should be pointing to one node above NodeToBeDeleted, not to the same node.

Comment: Quick question, you say that I am losing the rest of my list, and you are correct, I am, but how's come when I run the program and delete a node, the rest of my list still outputs correctly? If I lost the remainder of my list, it shouldn't display correctly, but it does, which is what is confusing me.

Comment: Sorry I missed this, better late than never.  The reason the list still outputs correctly is that nothing actually happens to your block of memory during the delete call.  The memory is just marked as free in the heap manager.  The data you store stays in memory until it is overwritten (usually on a subsequent call to new).

Comment: That makes sense, I appreciate you coming back to answer.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could get a memory leak is that you use an uninitialized variable in this test:

```
while (CharFound != 1)
```

`CharFound` is passed in from the calling function (`TestDeleteNode`), which does not initialize the variable `CharFound`.

if `CharFound` was passed in with a value of 1 (which could happen), then you would not go through your loop at all, in which case you would only execute

```
PlaceHolder->Link=PlaceHolder->Link->Link;
```

which would leak the memory at 'PlaceHolder->Link'

In the normal case, as @Ivan said, you are accessing the object after it has been deleted, both where Ivan mentioned (`NodeToBeDeleted->Ch`), but also in `PlaceHolder->Link->Link` as you will have `deleted` the memory pointed to by `PlaceHolder->Link` by then.

Comment: I actually just fixed the first issue you pointed out, by assigning 0 to CharFound after it enters the function.  I will look into the second half or your comment.